# after successful symlink, file url is not working in browser

Tags: laravel

i am usign laravel and facing some issue on symlink on live server.

i created symlink between public/storage and storgae/app/public using following command.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

and i got this response.

```
The [/home/www/thetripclub/public/storage] link has been connected to [/home/www/thetripclub/storage/app/public].
```

The links have been created.

when i go to public folder using `cd www/thetripclub/public`
i can see "storage" folder generated over there and all the folder and files from "storage/app/public" inside it.

but still i am unable to view the image using follwing link

```
https://app.happyvoyaging.com/storage/u-7/2021/08/21/goa-1629536543.jpg
```

i see blank page.

i have followed everything but this is not working at all.
on local system, it was working file but after moving to server, its not working.

after moving to server, i deleted the storage folder in public using and created storage link again, but no luck.

Comment: Does the file exists? I mean `/home/www/thetripclub/storage/app/public/u-7/2021/08/21/goa-1629536543.jpg`.

Comment: yes this file is over there.

Comment: It could be an issue with your webserver configuration. Are you using Nginx? Apache? Can you edit your question webserver details and config please? Ty

Comment: Hi Toyi, this is Apache and i am using php v7.4, what kind of config you want me to write over here from server.

Comment: The vhost file to start. the one defining the domain

Comment: Yes as @N69S stated, we need the vhost. It is located in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` (and should be symlinked in `/etc/apache2/sites-enable`).